# What does a variable defined as `Class<SomeProtocol> myClass` mean?

Tags: objective-c, class, variable-declaration, objective-c-protocol

I am used to seeing things like `id<NSCopying> myVar` or `MyObject<NSCopying> myVar`, where we are stating that the variable in question can happily have `NSCopying` methods called on it without the compiler throwing a wobbly.

But I recently spotted some code that defined a variable like this:

```
Class<NSCopying> myClass;
```

I was wondering what this actually means as it seems subtly different from the top two examples. It seems like we're saying that the variable `myClass` can happily accept method calls from `NSCopying` - but having a **class type** able to accept these **instance** variable methods doesn't seem to make much sense.

It has occurred to me that variables of type class are technically objects themselves which is probably confusing me or the compiler (probably me!).

So I guess I'm asking:

1. What does something like `Class<NSCopying> myClass;` actually mean
2. How does `Class<NSCopying> myClass;` differ to something like `id<NSCopying> myVar`
3. Where could something like `Class<NSCopying> myClass;` be meaningfully used?

Notes:

- I am just using `NSCopying` as an example and isn't integral to my use case
- Wherever I refer to `Class` I mean the Obj-C keyword `Class` for declaring variables that are of type `Class`. I am not using this as a generic term for any class type.

Answer (score 0):

```
id <NSCopying> myVar
```

Using `id` you can supply an instance of any type of class (so long as it implements the protocol, or you cast it to make the compiler trust you).

```
Class <NSCopying> myClass
```

Using `Class` means you can only supply a `Class`, not an instance.

Say you wanted your app to be configurable. Say you had a number of classes which offered a number of different features, but you didn't care about inheritance they had, just how to create and configure them. You could use a protocol that the class has to conform to and offer a method where the classes can be registered. Then you can instantiate those classes using the defined protocol without knowing anything else about the class.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I probably wasn't very clear about my use of the term `Class` - please see my edit for clarification. Thanks!

Comment: "you can only supply a Class, not an instance" Well, class objects *are* objects, i.e. instances.

Comment: @newacct, trying to work with easily understandable terminology. Open to suggestions to improve the description though.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think it might mean that `Class <NSCopying> myClass` points to a class that implements NSCopying protocol. It can be useful if protocol has class method declarations and you want to call them.

For example:

```
    @protocol NSSecureCoding <NSCoding>
       @required
       // The Secure Coding Guide should be consulted when writing methods that decode data.
       + (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding;
    @end
```

Comment: No, Objective-C has no type safety for class objects. You can't express "A class object of type NSString" or "A class that conforms to protocol X".

Answer (score 0):

`Class<ProtocolName>` is the type of a variable pointing to a class object with a meta class that conforms to `ProtocolName`. In other words: The class implements the methods from `ProtocolName` with **class methods**.

Example: `NSCopying` contains one required method:

```
@protocol NSCopying
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;
@end
```

`Class<NSCopying>` means that there is a method

```
+ (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;
```

in the class being pointed to. That is true for all `NSObject` derived classes and useful for using class objects as dictionary keys. [See the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/copyWithZone%3a).

Comment: @newacct Right, of course, thanks for making that clear! The meta class only informally conforms to the protocol by implementing the methods from the protocol.